# How to get terraform plan to create a private AKS cluster and namespace within the cluster?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

I have thee following cluster, and it creates fine. But I also want to add a kubernetes_namespace resource so that a namespace gets created after the private cluster is recreated. But how do I get terraform to actually connect to the private cluster after it creates?

```js
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  for_each            = var.aks_clusters
  name                = "aks-${each.key}-${var.env}-001"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "test-${each.key}-aks-cluster"
  kubernetes_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
  private_cluster_enabled = true  #false until networking is complete
  private_cluster_public_fqdn_enabled = true
  #
  # - Name must start with a lowercase letter, have max length of 12,
  #   and only have characters a-z0-9.
  #
  default_node_pool {
    name                  = substr("test${each.key}",0,12)
    vm_size               = var.aks_cluster_vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb       = var.aks_cluster_os_size_gb
    orchestrator_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    availability_zones    = [1, 2]
    enable_auto_scaling   = true
    max_count             = var.node_max_count
    min_count             = var.node_min_count
    node_count            = var.node_count
    type                  = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id        = var.aks_subnets[each.key].id
    node_labels = {
      "type"              = each.key
      "environment"       = var.env
    }
    tags = {
      "type"              = each.key
      "environment"       = var.env
    }
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
    pod_cidr = var.aks_subnets[each.key].pcidr
    service_cidr = var.aks_subnets[each.key].scidr
    docker_bridge_cidr = var.aks_subnets[each.key].dockcidr
    dns_service_ip = var.aks_subnets[each.key].dnsip
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = var.aks_app_id
    client_secret = var.aks_password
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
  }
  
  tags = local.resource_tags
}
```

Comment: Hello @shan, If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

with a private build agent in the same VNet or in a peered VNet. The Terraform State should be stored in a blob container or wherever you want, just not locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this from the *local machine*, it's not possible as the *Terraform client* won't be able to resolve the API server's IP address and send REST calls to it if they are on different networks in case of a private AKS cluster.

The best option would be to install the Terraform client on a machine in the network where you would like to deploy the AKS cluster or a connected network. In any case, the network has to be created before attempting to create the cluster. This is because when you are creating a namespace with Terraform in an AKS cluster, the provider is no longer `azurerm_*` and it will try to directly access the API server (it does not send a REST API call to ARM, like the `az aks command invoke`).

**Error from the local machine for a private cluster:**

[image]

But it will be possible for a public cluster:

[image]

---

So, for a *workaround* you can create a VM in the same vnet that you will be using for the AKS cluster and deploy the terraform script from inside the VM.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name = "resourcegroup"
}
data "azurerm_subnet" "aks-subnet" {
  name = "default"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "ansuman-aks-001"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  dns_prefix          = "ansuman-aks-cluster"
  private_cluster_enabled = true
  private_cluster_public_fqdn_enabled = true

  default_node_pool {
    name                  = "default"
    vm_size               = "Standard_D2_v2"
    availability_zones    = [1, 2]
    enable_auto_scaling   = true
    max_count             = 4
    min_count             = 1
    node_count            = 2
    type                  = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id        = data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
    dns_service_ip = "10.1.0.10"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "170.10.0.1/16"
    service_cidr = "10.1.0.0/16"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = "f6a2f33d-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx"
    client_secret = "mLk7Q~2S6D1Omoe1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
  }

}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_config.0.host}"
  username               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_config.0.username}"
  password               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_config.0.password}"
  client_certificate     = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate}")
  client_key             = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_config.0.client_key}")
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate}")
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "app_namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-namespace"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you want to verify if the namespace is added or not then open portal from your VM only and then you can verify as they are on same network.

For more information on how to connect to a private aks_cluster, you can refer the below link.

**Reference:**

[Create a private Azure Kubernetes Service cluster - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#options-for-connecting-to-the-private-cluster)